# Why am I getting 401 error from Firebase when requesting via HTTP using Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, http

I have this service where I would log in as an admin user. If logged in successfully I get a token from getIdToken and store it in localstorage. I console blogged it and it is a long token.

```
async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      const user = result.user;
      if(user){
        this.loggedIn = true;
        const token = await user.getIdToken(true);
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/listWebsites']);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  async getUserToken(): Promise<string | null> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    return token ? token : null;
  }
```

When I do a post Requests, I get the token from the service, I tried console log it and it seems to be fine but the response I get from Firebase is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

```
  async saveDetails() {
    try {
      const token = await this.authService.getUserToken();
      if (!token) {
        console.log('User is not authenticated');
        return;
      }
      console.log('Token:', token);
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      };
      const url = this.myUrl;
      
      this.http.post(url, this.detailsForm.value, { headers } )
        .subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            console.log('Patch Response:', data);
          },
          (error: any) => {
            console.error('HTTP Error:', error);
          }
        );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unexpected Error:', error);
    }
  }
```

There are my Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth !== null"  
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried sending the uid, I tried changing the header structure, Firebase rules, Firebase configuration but nothing worked.

Comment: Which Firebase REST API do you use? What is your URL? Other question: Any specific reason for using an API and not the JS SDK?

Comment: This is the API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database. I cannot share the URL here because it is not fully p[rotected and someone could make requests to it. The reason I preferred the API is because I find it cleaner. Do you recommend I look into a different kind of authorization ? using JS SDK ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by adding `?auth=${token}` at the end of the url but I am not sure this is very safe...